# Does overclocking affect the SPI (APB) clock?

Tags: overclocking, spi

The current `config.txt` allows one to change `arm_freq`, `gpu_freq`, `core_freq`, `h264_freq`, `isp_freq`, and `v3d_freq`. In addition, there is support for the kernel to change clocks on demand and based on thermal limits.

On the other hand, the hardware peripheral clock is described as:

> The Raspberry Pi runs the BCM2835 with a core clock of 250MHz. This is
>   relevant for the peripheral modules like I2C, SPI and Timer ( ARM side
>   ) for calculating the desired clock rate.

Elsewhere, this is described as the `Advanced Peripheral Bus (APB)` clock, and references are made to APB clock domain.

Now, my questions are:

- Do any of the `config.txt` settings affect the APB clock used for SPI?
- Does on demand `cpufreq` changing affect the APB clock used for SPI?
- Is there a way to determine this clock from Linux userland, or should it be hardcoded to 250 MHz for all current and future Raspberry Pi's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `core_freq` is a setting responsible for that clock as I saw some foundation members mentioning APB is a internal clock driven by GPU (but I haven't found a definitive proof for that). You should not threat it like a static value but I don't know how it can be determined from userspace.

Also by default, if `turbo_mode=0`, cpufreq will be changed according to system load. It should be between `core_freq_min` and `core_freq` which both, defaults to 250.

On the other hand, kernel SPI driver seems to be using `sdhost_clk` (according to `arch/arm/mach-bcm2708/bcm2708.c` file) clock which seems to be set as static 250Mhz. `cpufreq` driver does not change this value (as far as I can see, it only sets ARM clock but it is doing this through GPU which may adjust other frequencies by itself automatically).

Comment: Thank you. Even though not certain, that's probably the best answer I can get, short of actually proving that by experimentation, which I might do.

Comment: I have verified this experimentally - changing `core_clock` changes the SPI clock. I don't know if there is some other setting that also affects SPI clock, but atleast `core_clock` does. As for the kernel, many things are hardcoded and not really quite how they should be. I guess this is one of those things.