# Why is my zero SPI clock frequency different than requested?

Tags: pi-zero, spi, measuring

Using the SPIdev, I have setup the SPI clock frequency, but measuring the real signal frequency using oscilloscope shows, it differs extremely to the expectations. How is this possible?

```
spi_fd = open(device, O_WRONLY);
ret = ioctl(spi_fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed_hz);
```

**EDIT:**

```
uname -a
Linux zero2 4.9.22+ #987 Fri Apr 14 23:13:48 BST 2017 armv6l GNU/Linux

lsmod | grep spi
spidev                  7034  0
spi_bcm2835             7424  0

cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
700000
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
1000000
```

Comment: I can't say I have noticed any particular problem.  Which speeds have you set and what was the measured speed?

Comment: On 700MHz it's 62.5% of requested speed (625kHz for 1MHz, 1.25 MHz for 2MHz etc). On 1GHz it is 100%.

Comment: It may be because you are overclocking.  I would sort of expect timings to be a bit iffy in that case.  I tend to only use slow speeds when I'm testing and haven't seen discrepancies.  When I get a chance I'll connect a logic analyser and try at a few megahertz.

Comment: The clocking setup is default, until now I wasn't aware of the fact also RPi suffers from the `overclocking` obsession

Comment: The zero looks overclocked because it runs by default at 1 Ghz.  I suspect this is just the result of [binning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_binning).

Comment: @sharpener I have hooked up a logic analyser to the SPI signals on a Pi Zero and it certainly looks odd.  I don't remember seeing such discrepancies before - but that could be either my faulty memory or perhaps something has changed in the software.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least following reasons for this:

1. Considering the `ioctl` name, looks like the speed is only guaranteed not  to be greater than the value requested.
2. Due to some confusings in the Broadcom datasheets, the older SPI driver `spi-bcm2708` calculated the clock multiplier to be power of two instead of multiply of two. So the range of possible values was strongly reduced. This should be ok in the current driver `spi-bcm2835`. Check the current module loaded via `lsmod`.
3. Not sure why, but the SPI clock depends on the CPU clock. At least on my raspbian system, using the `spi-bcm2835` driver, the real clock frequency meets the expectations on *full speed* only (1GHz). At the default *idle speed* (700MHz) the SPI clock is lower (e.g. 12.5MHz real for 20MHz request). Check/change the current CPU speed settings:

   ```
   cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor                #current policy
   echo performance > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor #max performance

   cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq    #min CPU clock frequency
   cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq    #current CPU clock frequency
   cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq    #max CPU clock frequency
   ```

**EDIT:**

After some more research, regarding the *overclocking*, following parameters in `/boot/config.txt` affect the SPI clock. Using the values provided the real timing meets the expectations.

```
arm_freq=700
arm_freq_min=700   #effectively disable scaling
core_freq=200      #not sure about exact meaning, but this allows precise SPI clock setup
core_freq_min=200
```

There is a tool able to determine either configured or real clock values of the *overclocking* parameters:

```
vcgencmd get_config arm_freq
vcgencmd get_config core_freq
vcgencmd measure_clock arm
vcgencmd measure_clock core
```

So the *overclocked* system in full performance mode (correct SPI setting) is 1000(arm)/400(core)MHz.

[Nice summary for raspberry pi config options](http://elinux.org/RPiconfig)

Comment: You can get the current core clock setting with `vcgencmd measure_clock core`.  I believe the default is 250 Mhz.  See also https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3400/does-overclocking-affect-the-spi-apb-clock?rq=1